# NodeJS request works local, not on VPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vps

In a NodeJS project, I send a `request` to get the html of a webpage. This works fine when I run the code on my MacBook, but the request times out when I run the same code on my VPS. I don't know a lot about servers, so I have no idea where to look.

This is the `request` I send:

```
request({
  uri: 'http://torrentz.eu/search?f=' + encodeURIComponent(data.query)
, headers: {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2',
  }
}, console.dir);
```

Error:

```
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
```

---

**Edit:**

Other `request`s (like the one below) work fine.

```
request({
    uri: 'http://api.trakt.tv/account/test/' + config.trakt.apiKey
  , method: 'post'
  , form: {
        username: data.username
      , password: data.password
    }
}, function( err, resp, data ) {
  if( data.status === 'success' ) {
    User.set({
        trakt_username: data.username
      , trakt_password: data.password
    }).then(defer.resolve).catch(defer.reject);
  }
  else {
    defer.reject( data.error );
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that your VPS provider is blocking traffic to specific sites? Are you able to `curl` the problematic url from the command line on the VPS?

Comment: I also think your VPS might be blocking torrentsite or that torrentsite is rate-limiting your VPS because it is getting a lot of traffic from them.

Comment: If I ping the site, I get a response. But if I `curl`, I get this error `curl: (7) Failed connect to torrentz.eu:80; Bewerking is nu bezig`. The last part means something along the lines of "Editing is taking place right now".

Comment: if curl is failing, it's outside of node... since you can ping, it's likely torrentz.eu is blocking your request/ip (for any number of reasons).